# PHP8.1 - Should enums be in their own file?

Tags: php, class, enums

I want to start making use of [enumerations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.php) in PHP now that they are natively supported, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to organize and implement them. In my mind, they're more of a well-structured class constant. For instance I have a namespace like:

```
 - plugins\
   - Base
   - Products
   - Orders
   - Connector
   - pluginX\
     - Base
     - Connector
     ...
   - pluginY\
     - Base
     - Connector
     ...
```

The `Connector` is a Curl Wrapper class that can be used to make calls specific to the plugin. It has an abstract class that has some constants like `const GET = 'GET'`, `const POST = 'POST'` and base functions like `request` which takes `$method` -- a string of a valid HTTP method. The other `Connector` classes extend that with more specific functionality.

To me, the abstract base class seems like a great candidate for a simple `enum METHOD` that enforces one of the 5 valid methods. However, if I try organizing it like the following:

```
<?php

namespace Plugins;

enum Method: string
{
    case GET = 'GET';
    case PUT = 'PUT';
    case POST = 'POST';
    case PATCH = 'PATCH';
    case DELETE = 'DELETE';
}

abstract class Connector
{
    ...
}
```

I get an IDE warning that `Another class is declared in this file`. So it seems like Enums are treated as classes, and including them in the same file as other classes might violate a PSR-4 standard or something.

So should these enums all be living in their own classes? If so, I'm left unsure how to organize them since A. they may not fit neatly into the namespace and B. seems like my project would start to get littered by all these little files that are just single `enums`.

What's the best way to organize these?

Comment: i have your same problem. I think this should not be the case and enum should be able to be in the same file of another class. Right now you either litter the project with enum files or you just avoid using them when they are not super important

Answer (score 1):

yes, they are objects, stripped classes, you should put them in their own files.

read some more about them in this RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/enumerations